# Как сделать whitelist систему для discord бота с помощью txt документа?

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Код на данный момент:

```
wl = [652953834360143876,804342605034553345, 729715610774274180,758091017520939058] 

@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 60, commands.BucketType.user)
async def whitelist(ctx):
  author = ctx.message.author

  if ctx.author.id in wl:
    await ctx.send("You in whitelist")
  else:
    await ctx.send("You not in whitelist")
```

Я хотел бы сделать так, чтобы можно было добавлять людей командой с помощью текстового документа, а также удалять людей из whitelist.

Comment: Посмотрите на сохраните списка в json и загрузки из него, можно посмотреть configparser как вариант.

Comment: Можно по подробней? Просто для меня discord.py в новинку.

Answer (score 0):

для примера json:

```py
import json

wl = [652953834360143876,804342605034553345, 729715610774274180,758091017520939058] 

# Сохранить в файл
with open("data_file.json", "w") as write_file:
    json.dump(wl, write_file)

# Загрузить из файла
with open("data_file.json", "r") as read_file:
    data2 = json.load(read_file)
    print(data2)
```

А дальше уже логика как Вы хотите добавлять или удалять.
Например добавить новых людей из файла в wl:

```py
for i in data2:
    if i in wl:
        print("Есть в списке")
    elif i not in wl:
        wl.append(i)
print(wl)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!